# Send message from telegram bot to viber bot

Tags: laravel, telegram, telegram-bot, viber, viber-api

I have a bot working on Laravel Framework, there is a need to send a message to Viber bot. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

As I know Telegram doesn't support API to sending messages to external systems like Viber.

But you always can send message from Telegram bot to your server, and then forward this message from server to Viber.